# Pass updated super class values to subclasss

Tags: java

I am trying to pass a value that has been updated in the super class to the subclass is this possible?

For example I have:

```
public class1{
    @FXML
    ListView <String> list;

    // then list gets changed in a method

    public void method (){
    list.getItems().add("hello");
    }
}
```

And in a different class:

```
public anotherClass extends class1{

    public void method(){
    System.out.println(list);
    // here it seems that the list has not been updated and I get a null value when printing it instead of a list filled with "hello"
    }
}
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
public anotherClass extends class1{

    public void method(){
      super.method ();
      System.out.println(list);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you override the `method` in `class1`. Generally, we write such code like this:

```
class anotherClass extends class1 
{
    @Override // Since you replace the method in class1
    public void method()
    {
        // do something
```

If you're trying to  call the method defined in `class` at the same time as when you call the method in `anotherClass`, call it using the `super` keyword:

```
public void method()
{
    super.method();
    // do something else!
```